# Checking the authentication JWT token in azure function using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, azure-functions

I want to do a CRUD api in azure function using a token jwt in node.js.

1. I have a user who logs in with a login and password, after
   successful login I generate a token and store on local storage.
2. If a given user sends a request e.g. GET /basic-data I have to do
   verify token using 'jsonwebtoken' package by using middleware in
   azure function which will check if the token in the header is the
   same as the one in storage.

What the problem is that, I cannot call the middleware which is verify the jwt token in azure function.

For instance: if it is written in express, we can call the under like below:

```
const verifytoken = require("./middleware/auth");
app.get("/welcome/bubble", verifytoken, async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    status: res.statusCode,
    userInfo: res.req.user,
  });
```

});

But in azure function:

```
const response = require("../traits/api_response");
const Database = require("../model/database");
const config = require("../config/config");
const verifyJWT = require("../middleware/auth");

module.exports = async function (context, req, verifyJWT) {
  context.log("JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
  const { userId } = context.bindingData;
  console.log("Getting from the localhostlink: ", userId);
  if (!userId) {
    req.status(404).json(response.error([], `User ID must put!`));
    return;
  }

  try {
    const database = new Database(config);
    const user = await database.findID(userId);

    context.res = {
      status: 200,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: response.success(
        user,
        `Successfully going into the MS Sql server to get login information.`
      ),
    };
    database.disconnect();
  } catch (err) {
    context.res = {
      status: 500,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: `${err.message}`,
    };
  }
};
```

Could you please help that how can i call the middleware in azure function for JWT token? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

**Here is the code to check the authentication JWT token in azure function using Node.js:**

```js
const  jwToken = require("jsonwebtoken");
module.exports = async  function (context, req) {
try {
// Decode the json web token in the Authorization Header.

const  decodedToken = jwt.decode(req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]);

context.res =
decodedToken.scp.split(" ").indexOf("You provided") > -1
? {
body:  "Hello, world. You provided a valid access token.",
}

: { body:  "Missed required scope.", status:  403 };
} catch (error) {
context.res = { body:  "Improper Token......", status:  403 };
}
};
```

**Output:**
[image]

[image]

**Note:**

- Function app authentication does not allow a local development environment that is identical to the on-Azure runtime.
- The Azure Function app service's authentication capabilities won't be used if this is performed locally using the `func start` command, and any JWT token validation for authorization (signature, iss, exp, AUD) will be ignored by using this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-docs-code-javascript/ms-identity-docs-code-functions-nodejs/).
- For other approach please visit [GitHub](https://github.com/gitdagray/user_auth).