# What is a good Typescript middleware pattern for Azure Functions v4/v5?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jwt, azure-functions

I'm building a backend in Azure Functions and will split / modularise various bits of functionality across multiple function apps. The project is a port from a NodeJs app where the `.use()` features provided the middleware functionality.

Inside the functions I want application level authentication using JWT. I'm looking for a standard way I can have all functions do this authentication in a consistent way for all functions in the function app.

I've found this article that seems to be describing what I'm after, but I'm not sure of how to translate the pattern into my use case:

https://medium.com/medialesson/azure-functions-in-typescript-rest-crud-with-azure-table-storage-f54839db09e3

Additionally, there is this article and npm package that looks like it provides exactly what I'm after:

https://emanuelcasco.medium.com/improve-your-azure-functions-with-this-best-practices-da8fd0123318

and

https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-middleware?source=post_page-----da8fd0123318--------------------------------

However, the npm package hasn't been updated for 4 years and I'm reticent to use something that looks orphaned or abandoned. I haven't found any Azure Function examples (or any examples) of it's use beyond the NPM ReadMe.

Can anyone share how they have achieved a JWT middleware pattern for Typescript Azure Functions please?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a consistent JWT authentication middleware pattern for your TypeScript-based Azure Functions involves creating a custom middleware function that can be used across all of your functions. This middleware would be responsible for validating the JWT  and ensuring that the incoming requests are authenticated before they reach your individual functions.

**Here is way to acheive**
First, create a TypeScript file (e.g., `jwtMiddleware.ts`) where you'll define your JWT middleware function

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import * as jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const JWT_SECRET = "your-secret-key";
const JWT_ALGORITHM = "HS256";
type jwt = /*unresolved*/ any
export function jwtMiddleware(handler: AzureFunction): AzureFunction {
    return async (context: Context, req: HttpRequest) => {
        const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];

        if (authHeader) {
            const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
            try {
                const decoded = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET, { algorithms: [JWT_ALGORITHM] });
                req.user = decoded as jwt; // Cast to JwtPayload
            } catch (error) {
                context.res = {
                    status: 401,
                    body: "Invalid token",
                };
                return;
            }
        } else {
            context.res = {
                status: 401,
                body: "Token not provided",
            };
            return;
        }

        // Call the next handler in the chain
        await handler(context, req);
    };
}
```

In your individual Azure Functions, you can now use the `jwtMiddleware` function to ensure authentication

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import jwtMiddleware from "./jwtMiddleware";

const myFunction: AzureFunction = async (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> => {
    // JWT middleware is invoked here first
    await jwtMiddleware(context, req);

    // Your function logic here
    context.res = {
        status: 200,
        body: "Authenticated and authorized!",
    };
};

export default myFunction;
```

Now it able achieved a JWT middleware pattern for Typescript Azure Functions

[image]

Comment: Hi @SaiVamshiKrishna thanks for taking the time to provide a response.  However, it's not really a middleware pattern that you provide, but more an object oriented reusable class for use in each function.  If I understand the provided article correctly (the first link ) it uses the middleware as a wrapper for all functions, rather than all functions needing to import / execute the class as a statement.

What I'm hoping for is something perhaps like what the article I link below does for `HttpRequest` (extends it to `InputHttpRequest`), but for the `AzureFunction` class).

Comment: See https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2019-04-03-typed-bindings-for-azure-functions/

Comment: Please refer to these links
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76456350/checking-the-authentication-jwt-token-in-azure-function-using-node-js)
For other approach please visit  [GitHub](https://github.com/gitdagray/user_auth).

Comment: Hi again @SaiVamshiKrishna, apologies if my question is not clear but it's asking not so much about JWT tokens, but more middleware patterns.

The middleware pattern enforces a pre-processing for all requests without the need for each request to call that code.  It uses the NodeJs Express routing where an interception occurs and enforces checking (whether JWT, user account existence, or anything) that then uses the `.next()` method to continue processing which ever route was called.

Your suggestions all require explicit inclusion of the processing in each route. That's not what I'm after.